# Proper Docker Setup for Multiple Websites

Tags: php, ssl, nginx, docker, scaling

I'm wondering what the proper flow is for a setup to host multiple websites using  a simple LEMP stack. Suppose I have a VM from Digital Ocean. I want to host 3 websites on this one VM. 
To accept requests, I either have a HAproxy container or Nginx virtual host container sitting at the front. That then routes the specific requests to a stack of containers that handles the application

Requests => Nginx/HAproxy =>

(website1.com) => (Nginx, php-fpm, mysql stack)

(website2.com) => (Nginx, php-hpm, mysql stack)

(website3.com) => (Nginx, php-hpm, mysql stack)

If this is the proper setup, how do I go about scaling the individual websites. If website 2 gets a lot more traffic, and needs more containers would I scale up the entire stack (nginx, php-fpm, mysql) x2 or do I let the Nginx container at the front of the stack load balance between multiple php-fpm instances?

website2.com => 1(nginx, php-fpm, mysql) or 2(nginx, php-fpm, mysql) using round robin.

OR

website2.com => (nginx, php-fpm, php-fpm, php-fpm, mysql) where that nginx container handles round robin between the php-fpm containers.

Further side note, where do I place my SSL certificates for each website? Do I put them in the HAproxy/Nginx virtual host container, or do I just have the exist in the stack nginx container.

Comment: This is really difficult to answer, especially since you seem to be asking several questions at once. I'd suggest breaking this up into several more specific questions (at the very least, the question about whether to colocate nginx with the application stack and SSL as separate). It would also be helpful to know whether you can start off with multiple server or not as answers could dictate whether stuff like Docker Swarm, overlay networking, and discovery concepts get involved. As is, there are so many different ways this could be answered.

Comment: What do you mean by starting off with multiple servers or not?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, be aware that containers are supposed to run a single process, not stacks. Although it's possible to run an *init-like* process spawning multiple processes inside a single container, or even something like [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to achieve this, that's not a best practice. Containers were meant to be used as micro-services.

So, without considering the database, one possible scenario would be:

1. Multiple *application containers*, one per website, running *php-fpm*;
2. One single *webserver container*, running *Nginx* and including a *vhost* config for each website, and linked to all your application containers;
3. One single *load balancer* container, running whatever you choose as a solution for proxy-balancing, with all the configuration needed for the websites, including SSL.

So, I understand you would have, at least 2 layers: Load Balancer/Proxy -> Applications. So, 3) goes in the upper layer, and 1) and 2) goes in the other, which are supposed to run on the same server.

Regarding the database service, I'm not sure it's a good choice to run it in a container. You would have to map a data directory from the host (because containers are ephemeral, but your data is not), and it wouldn't make sense to be moving around your container to other servers without moving data along, so a container seems quite useless in this case. And you won't use the container to leverage deployments in this case, anyway, so I can't see much advantage in it. It would be better just to have another server for the database.

About scaling, if you decide to run all sites on the same server, you don't have much choice but scaling everything together. Alternatively, you could split things up by service. You would have a group of machines for each "microservice" (lets say, *website1+nginx1*, *website2+nginx2*, etc). This way you could scale every service independently, but this would probably mean a lot of overhead and resource waste. It all depends on how complex you think you need to get.

This is not an easy question to answer and there isn't right and wrong when it comes to architectures like that. It's just a matter of deciding what is a good trade-off to you.

Comment: Yes, when I said stack, I was using it informally to essentially describe a docker-compose file. That is, one "stack" is 3 containers one of nginx, php-fpm, etc. I understand that I would likely need a better volume manager if I'm going to be running mysql in the container, but I think I'm more concerned with the scaling of php-fpm as opposed to scaling both nginx, and php-fpm for the same website.

Comment: Further, wouldn't I need more than just one nginx container? Otherwise all my files would have to be in that container as opposed to running seperate nginx containers per application.

Comment: Yes, like I said, it depends on how you are going to split your applications. If you're going to run everything on the same server, I would rather have a single Nginx container with all configs than one Nginx per website. But another approach is to have, for each website, a Nginx+PHP-FPM pair, maybe in the same container. This way, you container is more "self-contained", and functional. It's up to you to decide.